# Solr CSV responses writer: How to get no encapsulator

Tags: csv, solr

I need to get back CSV output from my Solr queries, so I am using Solr's CSV responses writer.

All works fine using `wt=csv` without changing default values for CSV output, but I have one requirement: I need tab-separated CSV with no text value quoting at all.

The tab-separation is easy as I can specify a tab as `csv.separator` in the Solr csv responses writer.

The problem is how to get rid of encapsulation:
The default values for encapsulation of csv fields is `"`.
But setting `encapsulator=''` or `encapsulator=None` returns the error `Invalid encapsulator`.

There seems to be no documentation for this in the [Solr Wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Response+Writers#ResponseWriters-CSVResponseWriter).

How can I suppress encapsulation at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not going to be able to, the java source expects a 1 char length encapsulator:

```
String encapsulator = params.get(CSV_ENCAPSULATOR);
String escape = params.get(CSV_ESCAPE);
if (encapsulator!=null) {
  if (encapsulator.length()!=1) throw new SolrException( SolrException.ErrorCode.BAD_REQUEST,"Invalid encapsulator:'"+encapsulator+"'");
  strat.setEncapsulator(encapsulator.charAt(0));
}
```

What you can do:

1. Write your own custom NoEncapsulatorCSVResponseWriter, by inheriting from CSVResponseWriter probably, and modify the code so it does not use the encapsulator. Not difficult, but mostly a hassle.
2. Use some unique encapsulator (for example ø) and then add a postprocess step on your client side that just removes it. Easier but you need that extra step...